inner Join cuando uno de las columnas tiene mas de un dato
espero se encuentren bien, llegue a un proyecto en donde me piden una consulta sql, pero el problema es que uno de las tablas tiene mas de un dato, el cual creo que es una mala practica
este es el caso.
necesito hacer el reporte de ventas
el codigo que me dieron y el que uso ahora es este
 $ventasQuery = Contract::select('contracts.*', 'users_seller.name AS seller_name', 'users_seller.store AS seller_store', 'users_store.name AS store_name');

    $ventas = $ventasQuery
        ->join('users AS users_seller', 'contracts.vendedor', '=', 'users_seller.id')        
        ->leftJoin('users AS users_store', 'users_seller.store', '=', 'users_store.id')
        ->orderBy('contracts.id', 'DESC')
        ->get();

(tampoco tengo mucha idea de por que lo ponen en dos variables diferentes)
el problema principal es que todos los entes que tienen relación con el sistema están en la tabla usuarios (tanto vendedores, como sucursales, como administradores y clientes), para poder mostrar los contratos y los vendedores y las sucursales, hice estos join, en donde traigo la tabla usuarios dos veces, una que muestre los vendedores users_seller y una para las sucursales users_store
pero también debo traer los administradores, el problema es que cuando trato con un join me da error, creo que es por como está hecha la tabla, la cual es algo así
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `store` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
)

por conveniencia muestro solo los datos importantes, entonces, todos los usuarios estan en la tabla usuarios, necesito traer el nombre de usuario (administrador) en donde users.id(store) sea igual a users.store(admin), pero ese tipo de usuario tiene varias "store"
sería algo así
users  (sucursal)    |  users (admin)
id (1)               |   store (1, 3, 7)

y al tratar de conectar me da error

Me resulto un poco confuso entender tu pregunta, entiendo en tu misma tabla esta el id de usuario, el tipo de usuario (que puede ser sucursal, cliente, usuario o proveedor) y al mismo tiempo la tiendas que tiene asignadas? eso parece mas una tabla pivote.
Pero porque no intentas ejecutar tu consulta primero en sql, o crear un stored procedure, digo esto para que en tu join hagas una subconsulta a la misma tabla y se vea un poco mas legible tu codigo Eloquent.
Algo como esto:
SELECT u.ID, s.Store FROM Users u
JOIN (SELECT ID, Store FROM Users) s ON u.Id = s.ID

